# When is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a(k) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b(k)\ge \sum _{k=1}^{\infty}a(k)b(k)?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given two convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a(k)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b(k)$ under what conditions is valid the inequality:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a(k)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b(k)\ge\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a(k)b(k)$$

Thanks.

Comment: The obvious condition : when $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative. Also $\sum_{k}a(k)b(k)$ need not converge in general.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: This holds also for complex series?

Comment: Thou shalt not use $\ge$ and $\le$ when complex numbers are involved.

Comment: @GregMartin: I agree. The $\ge$ and $\le$ should be considered for the modulus of the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sufficient condition is for the "cross-terms" $a(i)b(j)$, $i\ne j$ to be positive, which means that $\text{sgn}(a(i))=\text{sgn}(b(j))$, for all $i,j$.

Comment: This is equivalent to all the terms in both sequences being positive or all the terms in both sequences being negative.